# JMeter Get and store Body Data before Sending for further valdiation

Tags: json, jmeter

Sample json:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "Test sample 1",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to store the entire json into a variable using JSR223 preprocessor.

```
def body = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
vars.putObject('actual', body)
log.info("actual" + actual)
```

just the first argument data is stored. How to store the entire json. Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the response into a JMeter Variable using JSR223 PreProcessor you don't even need to parse it by any means, to wit remove the [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html), just save the request payload:

```
vars.put('actual', sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
```

[image]

Then `${actual}` JMeter Variable will hold the HTTP Request payload, you can verify it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Json object is a String, So instead decoding(parsing) json store it in string variable and decode when needed.